# ExtJS 4.2.3 set a panel collapse animation direction

Tags: animation, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJS 4.2.3

I need a panel to collapse with an animation with a left and right direction.

there are 2 panels the reside in an hbox container.

here is how I am calling the collapse

```
var me = this,
            direction = NG.isRTL() ? Ext.Component.DIRECTION_LEFT : Ext.Component.DIRECTION_RIGHT;

        me.collapse(direction);
```

No matter what I pass for the direction field I alweys get the animation working from right to left. (I need it the other way around)

I have searched the web for it but no one seems to talk about it.

Please see the image I have attached where I have captured the animation half way through.
[image]

UPDATE:

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I am talking about:
[example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j4k)

Comment: You should create a small self contained reproduction of your problem at  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home . You're not giving us a lot of information here

Comment: You need to check the result of your if statement and make sure that it is actually returning what you expect. The collapse function itself works fine for me when testing, your problem must be with your applications logic.

Comment: It does look like it's not working. I would file a bug with Sencha, if you are a support customer, that's the fastest way to get something like this resolved. You can use https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j4p as an example that shows that `Ext.Component.DIRECTION_RIGHT`,
`Ext.Component.DIRECTION_BOTTOM` don't seem to work.  My first impression was that it was because of the flow, as you collapse to the right, the elements flows to the left, but then I even created an absolute layout and it still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there could be a bug, see https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j4p. However, if you want collapsible panels on the right side to collapse to the right, you should just use a border layout. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j4q

```js
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Border Layout',
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'South Region is resizable',
        region: 'south', 
        height: 75,
        split: true
    },{
        title: 'East Region is collapsible',
        region:'east',
        width: 100,
        collapsible: true,
    },{
        title: 'West Region is collapsible',
        region:'west',
        width: 100,
        collapsible: true,
    },{
        title: 'Center Region',
        region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
        xtype: 'panel'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

```html
<link href="http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/styles-3eba09980fa05ead185cb17d9c0deb0f.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/resources/css/app-4689d2a5522dcd3c9e9923ca59c33f27.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```